# Set swappiness for allocated memory

Tags: c++, c, malloc

There's a way (even if exotic) to set the swappiness, or give hints to the OS about it, when allocating memory inside a C or C++ program?

Note that I do not want to set the swappiness for the entire process but at object/variable-level.

Comment: What do you mean by *swappiness*?

Comment: Swappiness is a Linux kernel parameter that controls the relative weight given to swapping out runtime memory, as opposed to dropping pages from the system page cache. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swappiness

Comment: It's a bit of a hammer, and doesn't provide any tuning, but POSIX provides `mlock()` and `mlockall()`.  It's not really an answer, but start here:  http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/mlock.html

Comment: First, since you don't swap individual objects or variables, you probably mean something like "want to do this at the *page* level".   Second, the swappiness parameter is not what you want, it's not even *per-process*.

Comment: So maybe take a step up and describe the higher-level problem that you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you can't do something this fine-grained without a custom allocator. Stuff like `mlock` and `posix_madvise` work on a page level, and they're basically on/off switches. So for the normal heap, you'd be tuning "swappiness" (however you define it) for the object you allocate and anything else that happens to share the same page(s), and if you subsequently allocated a new object with a different "swappiness" and it ended up in the same page, you'd overwrite the old setting.

To make this work, you'd basically need to maintain a bunch of separate heaps with different heap-global settings for "swappiness", and allocate objects to each heap as needed. And since overloading `operator new` is on a per-type basis, if you wanted to change the behavior for different objects of the same type, you're stuck manually performing raw allocations from each heap and performing placement `new`/`delete` to dynamically change the desired "swappiness".

No matter what you do, anything stack allocated couldn't use this approach, since the stack can't be split like this, so tuning "swappiness" for one stack object would also tune it for tons of stuff (variables and stuff like return address storage and register spills) as well.

Note: If you're talking about Linux kernel [swappiness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swappiness) as [@nicolacdnil suggests in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33809050/set-swappiness-for-allocated-memory/33809259#comment55383425_33809050), that's not possible. It's a kernel level setting that applies to the whole system, it's not even tunable on a per-process level, let alone a per-object level.

Comment: "It's a kernel level setting that applies to the whole system, it's not even tunable on a per-process level, let alone a per-object level." It's kind of what I was expecting. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mlock`:

```
struct MyStruct { // ... };

void * memory_pool = malloc(sizeof(MyStruct));
mlock(memory_pool, sizeof(MyStruct));

MyStruct * my_struct = new(memory_pool) MyStruct();

// (You must check all values returned by `malloc`, `mlock` and `new`!)
```

`my_struct` will be in physical memory and will not be swapped to disk until calling `munlock()` or process exit.

Comment: Of course, if you then `malloc` a second `MyStruct` and `mlock` it, odds are they'll show up in the same page. If you then `munlock` either of them prior to `free`-ing them, you'll `munlock` both of them. `mlock` is page granularity, and a boolean flag; any number of locks are undone by a single `munlock`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger You may get `memory_pool` large enough for all your objects, and use one `mlock` then.

Comment: Also, POSIX standards for `mlock`/`munlock` allows an implementation to require that the address passed for locking be page aligned, so your example isn't guaranteed to be portable. You'd need to explicitly force page alignment with something like `void *pool_base_addr = (void*)((intptr_t)memory_pool & ~(sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE) - 1)); mlock(pool_base_addr, memory_pool + sizeof(MyStruct) - pool_base_addr);`, ugly, but portable (might need a cast or two to silence signedness warnings).

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thanks for this note about aligment, forgot it.

Comment: Agreed on that much. Though it's not often the case that you can predict the total number of objects you need up front (and overestimating means unusable physical RAM, thanks to the `mlock`). In practice, you may as well write your own allocator (probably borrowing from `dlmalloc` or the like) to wrap generalized allocation of this form, but that's going to a huge effort for something that is probably best to leave up to the OS. :-)

Comment: @ShadowRanger Usually there are limited number of objects that must reside always in physical memory (objects that need extremely fast access unconditionally).